# Populate Listview based of dropdown selection c#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, listview

I am trying to populate a listview based on the selection made in a dropdown menu.

The dropdown menu has list of categories and I want the listview to display all films of that category. All this information is in mysql database.

I have achieved this with two dropdown menus but the code does not work with the listview because I get the following errors: 
*'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView' does not contain a definition for 'DataValueField' and no extension method 'DataValueField' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)* and the same error but replace 'DataValueField' with 'DataTextField'.

Code for dropdown:

```
public void ddl_Cat()
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            MySqlCommand sql_Category = new MySqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT(Category) FROM DVD", cs);
            cs.Open();

            MySqlDataReader ddlgetcat;
            ddlgetcat = sql_Category.ExecuteReader();

            ListViewCat.DataSource = ddlgetcat;
            ListViewCat.DataValueField = "Category";
            ListViewCat.DataTextField = "Category";
            ListViewCat.DataBind();
            cs.Close();
            cs.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Code for listview:

```
protected void ListViewCat_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string categorySelection = ddlCategory.SelectedValue;
        string available = string.Empty;
        {
            MySqlCommand cd_available = new MySqlCommand(String.Format("SELECT * FROM DVD WHERE (Cateogry) ='{1}' and (Title) ='{0}'", ddlCategory.SelectedItem.ToString().Trim(), categorySelection), cs);
            cs.Open();
            available = Convert.ToString(cd_available.ExecuteScalar());
            cs.Close();
            cs.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Can anybody help me to fix this code of provide an alternative to this method?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

That's because those 2 properties (DataValueField & DataTextField) do not exist on the asp List View control: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview(v=vs.110).aspx.  They do exist on the asp Drop Down List control: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Just like the error says, the `ListView` control does not have a `DataValueField` or `DataTextField` property. I think you are confusing this with the drop down list, where you can set those values.

Remove them from your code, like this:

```
public void ddl_Cat()
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        MySqlCommand sql_Category = new MySqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT(Category) FROM DVD", cs);
        cs.Open();

        MySqlDataReader ddlgetcat;
        ddlgetcat = sql_Category.ExecuteReader();

        ListViewCat.DataSource = ddlgetcat;
        ListViewCat.DataBind();
        cs.Close();
        cs.Dispose();
    }
}
```

---

> Note: Since `Category` is the only field returned from your `SELECT DISTINCT` query, then it will be the only field shown in your list view.